# Will new class be instantiated for different values of a non-type template argument

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

let's say i have the following code:

```
#define CHECK_BIT(var,pos) ((var) & (1<<(pos)))
enum open_mode {
    read = (1u << 0),
    write = (1u << 1),
    binary = (1u << 2),
    update = (1u << 3)
};

template<int open_type>
class file {
public:
    constexpr static int is_read_mode() {
        return CHECK_BIT(open_type,0);
    }
    constexpr static int is_write_mode() {
        return CHECK_BIT(open_type,1);
    }
    constexpr static int is_binary_mode() {
        return CHECK_BIT(open_type,2);
    }
    constexpr static int is_update_mode() {
        return CHECK_BIT(open_type,3);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T),is_read_mode()),size_t> read() {}

    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T),is_write_mode()),size_t> write() {}

};
```

My question is - is for every different value for open_type a new class file instantiated? because the following code compiles fine

```
int main() {
    file<open_mode::write> f; 
    f.write<int>();

    file<open_mode::read> f2; 
    f2.read<int>();
    //f2.write<int>();
}
```

since the is_*_mode() methods are static, this simply means a new class is instantiated, doesn't it?

Comment: "does for every other value for open_type a new class file is instantiated?" - yes.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any point to your `typename T` parameters in `read` and `write`. You are discarding the value of `sizeof(T)`

Comment: `template<> std::enable_if_t<is_read_mode(),size_t> read()` would do the same

Comment: And I'd find it easier to have `static constexpr bool is_read_mode = (open_type & open_mode::read);` than your function + macro + duplication of `0, 1, 2, 3`

Comment: i was using `std::enable_if_t<is_read_mode(),size_t> read()' but that was not compiling

Comment: @Caleth he would not be able to use enable_if if the function did not have a template parameter. Also, `T` must be incorporated to the signature of the function to make it compile. Using the comma operator to circumvent the compiler's fad in a case like this is a pretty imaginative way of doing so. I would have been using a default value for T, though, to eliminate the need for one when calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there will exactly as many classes exist as many total specialization with different template parameter lists given, regardless of what kind of template parameters the class template has. But as these classes' members are `constexpr` functions and their bodies can be compiled into a single `mov` instruction, they will get inevitably inlined when compiled with -On (n>0). That is, no matter how many total specializations of `file` template you have, there will be no extra complexity added to the binary.

Answer (score 0):

For every other value for `open_type` new type is introduced, e.g. class, 
so, one class of class family is defined and it has all static functions for that type,
if that is what you mean. Also, it could be, that its not true that

> new class file is instantiated

as you say,
but

> new `class file<open_type>` is instantiated

also, just to mention, please correct me if I'm wrong,
for that code to compile,

we need to return some size_t value from read or write 
functions, regarding which one instantiated using SFINAE.
I hope this helps.